# Wrong error message displayed on SO

Tags: support

Why do I get the error message "You can only post once in every 90 minutes", even when I am not posting twice any near to 90 mins. I posted yesterday around same time and now I am posting a whole of 24 hours later. still getting this cumbersome message.

Please check if something wrong with the implementation somewhere in the website.

Comment: So you mean you're able to post, as I've seen you do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040675/play-not-recognizing-datasource-in-play-db-db) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020957/ie10-support-for-google-maps), but you get the error message anyway? How does that happen? Do you see the error message when submitting the form before the browser redirects to your question?

Comment: No..the error message kept appearing for a while. It was only after waiting for at least 30 minutes and taking two new sessions that I was able to post successfully. Why should the error appear at the first place.

Comment: Is your IP addresses shared? That is, are you posting from an environment where the outbound IP address would be the same for many people? (University, work place etc?). If so, it could be that you are caught by someone _else_ posting.

Comment: Yes certainly it is such a place...In that case, I don't have any idea if the same IP is used for all out going posts. May be you are right.. I shall surely inquire this..
Anyways..thanks for providing a satisfactory reason.