# Is this expected behaviour?

Tags: bug, bounty

I just added a bounty to a week old question I had asked in order to attract attention to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236289/is-it-possible-to-have-lync-communicate-with-a-rest-api).

I now have a completely separate, new problem which I want to post about on Stack Overflow. Because I have made the bounty, however, I am prevented from doing this, with the following error message displayed :

[image]

I have not posted in the last 90mins, merely added a bounty to one of my existing posts.

I suspect this is a bug?

Thanks very much.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284069/wrong-error-message-displayed-on-so and several other questions on meta here. Try searching "90 minutes" and you'll see a bunch of them.

Comment: It essentially boils down to: Are you on a shared network? (i.e. internet cafe, school network, work network, etc.) If yes, someone else posted in the last 90 minutes and you'll have to try and catch it in a period where no one from your network has posted.

Comment: The problem is you bountied yourself below 125 rep and thus are subject to IP-level rate-limiting.